# Ruby array of arrays into array of hashes

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I have an array of arrays:

```
data = [
 ["Smith", "Bob", "Male"], 
 ["Jim", "Tim", "Male"],   
 ["Welch", "Anne", "Female"]
]
```

How would I convert it to look like:

```
data = [
 {:first_name => "Smith", :last_name => "Bob", :gender => "Male"},  
 {:first_name => "Jim", :last_name => "Tim", :gender => "Male"}, 
 {:first_name => "Welch", :last_name => "Anne", :gender => "Female"}
]
```

Comment: How did you get your AoA input? Can you share code you've tried to do the conversion?

Comment: `data.map { |f, l, g|  { :first_name => f, :last_name => l, :gender => g } }`

Answer (score 8):

You can do something like this:

```
fields = [:first_name, :last_name, :gender]
data.map {|row| fields.zip(row).to_h }

#=> [{:first_name=>"Smith", :last_name=>"Bob", :gender=>"Male"}, {:first_name=>"Jim", :last_name=>"Tim", :gender=>"Male"}, {:first_name=>"Welch", :last_name=>"Anne", :gender=>"Female"}]
```

Keep in mind that this will only work if the elements are in the same order as the fields.

Answer (score 1):

Also you could use `Struct`:

```
presenter = Struct.new(:first_name, :last_name, :gender)
data.map { |e| presenter.new(*e).to_h }
#=> [{:first_name=>"Smith", :last_name=>"Bob", :gender=>"Male"}, 
#    {:first_name=>"Jim", :last_name=>"Tim", :gender=>"Male"}, 
#    {:first_name=>"Welch", :last_name=>"Anne", :gender=>"Female"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fields = [:first_name, :last_name, :gender]
data.map{|d| Hash[fields.zip(d)]}
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, it doesn't provide any context to explain how or why. Consider adding a sentence or two to explain your answer. This may help both the asker of this question, and generations of future coders who come across this answer. :-)